# What is the difference between these two PhysicsVector methods?

Tags: java

Based on the comments they're supposed to do exactly the same thing. Except that, when I use 'add' instead of 'increaseBy', my code produces different outputs.

```
/**
* standard vector addition. If <b> v = xi + yj</b>
* and <b>u = wi + zy</b>, then the method returns a vector
* <b>(x+w)i + (y+z)j</b>
*
* @param v first vector in sum
* @param u second vector in sum
* @return return summed vector
**/
public static PhysicsVector add(PhysicsVector v, PhysicsVector u){
    PhysicsVector sum = new PhysicsVector(v);
    sum.increaseBy(u);
    return sum;
}
```

So that was one, and here's the other:

```
/**
* Add a vector <b>v</b> to the original vector. Normal vector
* addition is carried out. I.e. the x-components are added and
* the y components are added, etc.
*
* @param v vector to be added to original vector. 
**/
public void increaseBy(PhysicsVector v){
    for (int i=0; i<vectorComponents.length; i++) {
        vectorComponents[i] += v.vectorComponents[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: "Except that, when I replace one with the other, my code produces different outputs - why?" Which one do you replace with the other, and which one produces which output, and which output is right?

Comment: That's depends on the increaseBy of the PhysicsVector. Without the code, of the librairy that PhysicsVector is coming from, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @AndyTurner Neither output is right, in the middle of debugging - but replacing increaseBy with add makes it even more wrong!

Comment: But only because, based on the answer below, I was using the method wrong. result.add(u,v) seems to not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The former creates a *copy* of the vector `v`, increases it, and then returns that copy.  The latter actually *modifies* the original vector passed to it.

So:

```
PhysicsVector u = new PhysicsVector(1, 1);
PhysicsVector v = new PhysicsVector(2, 4);

PhysicsVector result = PhysicsVector.add(u, v);

// u and v are still (1, 1) and (2, 4), and result is (3, 5)
```

But with `increaseBy`:

```
PhysicsVector u = new PhysicsVector(1, 1);
PhysicsVector v = new PhysicsVector(2, 4);

u.increaseBy(v);

// u itself has now been changed to (3, 5)
```

Comment: so if I had a physicsvector called result, and then wrote result.add(u,v) is the answer stored in result? Or is that the wrong way to use the method?

Comment: `u.add(v)` on its own doesn't do anything.  You have to store the result somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Although the two methods perform the same task, they differ in the way they return their result:

- The first method produces a *new* `PhysicsVector` representing the sum, with no side effects as far as `v` and `u` are concerned.
- The second method performs addition *in place*, so the method is called for its side effect.

That's why you get different results when switching from one method to the other.

> `result.add(u,v)` seems to not work

Note that the structure of the API provides a hint of what is happening, because the first method is `static`. Calling the static method on an instance is an indication of a usage problem. What you needed to do instead was

```
result = PhysicsVector.add(u, v);
```